# Work with child EntitySet in databound detailsview

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, detailsview, entityset

I am working with ASP.Net (forms) and Linq To SQL. I have a parent table called Feedback, a table called Tags and a table called FeedbackTags which allows me to relate tags to feedback items. I have a master/detail view (GridView/DetailsView) which I use for editing/reviewing feedback.  FeedbackTags is an EntitySet(of FeedbackTags) property on Feedback.

To manage the list of tags associated with a specific feedback item I've created a user control which shows a list of all the tags with a checkbox next to each.  Each tag that is currently associated with this feedback item is checked.  This list is built by querying the list of tags and then for each one checking the FeedbackTags EntitySet to see if a cooresponding record exists and if it does noting the id.

Appearances wise it looks great, but it doesn't work.  I can't get two way databinding to work with my FeedbackTags entityset.  Are there any examples of how to get this sort of setup to work with Linq-To-Sql or do I have to write the code to make it work by hand?

Comment: Could you please post some code (Short relevant code example will be a very good), so that I can figure out your problem.